# Center point calculation for 3D polygon

Tags: c#, geometry

I'm attempting to work out the centre of a planar polygon, and was wondering what the best way to approach this is.

I have access to the vertices that form the polygon, but nothing else.

Does anyone have any suggestions for how to approach this?

Thanks.

Comment: By "planar polygon" I presume you mean a polygon in an unknown plane. If all you have is the 3D coordinates of the points, we can give you a (reversible) transformation, but there may be an easier way; by "centre", do you mean the centre of mass, the circumcentre, or something else?

Comment: Center of mass of the suface, the edges, the vertices ...?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wouldn't project to 2D.

## Center of mass

### Center of mass of the vertices

Sum the coordinates of all vertices, and divide by the number of vertices.
See [centroid of a finite set of points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid#Of_a_finite_set_of_points).

```
sx = sy = sz = 0
for i in 1..n:
    sx = sx + px[i]
    sy = sy + py[i]
    sz = sz + pz[i]
cx = sx/n
cy = sy/n
cz = sz/n
```

### Center of mass of the edges

Sum the centers of all edges, weighted by the length of these edges, and divide by the total circumference.

```
sx = sy = sz = slen = 0
x1 = px[n]
y1 = py[n]
z1 = pz[n]
for i in 1..n:
    x2 = px[i]
    y2 = py[i]
    z2 = pz[i]
    dx = x2 - x1
    dy = y2 - y1
    dz = z2 - z1
    len = sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy + dz*dz)
    sx = sx + (x1 + x2)/2*len
    sy = sy + (y1 + y2)/2*len
    sz = sz + (z1 + z2)/2*len
    slen = slen + len
    x1 = x2
    y1 = y2
    z1 = z2
cx = sx/slen
cy = sy/slen
cz = sz/slen
```

### Center of mass of surface

Triangulate the polygon, then sum the centers of mass of all triangles, weighted by their area, then divide by total area. You can choose a triangulation where not all the triangles are fully within the polygon, as long as the area outside is compensated for by triangles of a different orientation. The area of a triangle is half the length of the cross product of two of its edge vectors.

See [centroid of polygon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid#Centroid_of_polygon) for the 2D case, but more appropriately [centroid by geometric decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid#By_geometric_decomposition) for this approach using areas. Also see [centroid of triangle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid#Of_triangle_and_tetrahedron) for the fact that the center of mass for the surface of a triangle is equal to the center of mass for its vertices.

```
sx = sy = sz = sarea = 0
x1 = px[1]
y1 = py[1]
z1 = pz[1]
for i in 3..n:
    x2 = px[i-1]
    y2 = py[i-1]
    z2 = pz[i-1]
    x3 = px[i]
    y3 = py[i]
    z3 = pz[i]
    dx1 = x3 - x1
    dy1 = y3 - y1
    dz1 = z3 - z1
    dx2 = x3 - x2
    dy2 = y3 - y2
    dz2 = z3 - z2
    cpx = dy1*dz2 - dz1*dy2
    cpy = dz1*dx2 - dx1*dz2
    cpz = dx1*dy2 - dy1*dx2
    area = sqrt(cpx*cpx + cpy*cpy + cpz*cpz)/2
    sx = sx + (x1 + x2 + x3)/3*area
    sy = sy + (y1 + y2 + y3)/3*area
    sz = sz + (z1 + z2 + z3)/3*area
    sarea = sarea + area
cx = sx/sarea
cy = sy/sarea
cz = sz/sarea
```

Comment: You shouldn't have to worry about concave lines, the code should work for any polygon since the strange situations cancel out. You are right, my `px,py,pz` are coordinate arrays. Whether you use 1-based or 0-based indexing depends on your language, but since you ask, you probably want to start at 0. And also use `[n-1]` instead of `[n]` to access the last point before the edge loop. My answer is consistently written with 1-based pseudocode, since most math formulas are notated 1-based.

Answer (score 1):

I found I needed to make a small tweak to MvG mass centroid calculation to change point2 at the end of each loop to point3 (see "p2 = p3;" below).  I expect this is what he meant to do, so each area only counted once. Here is a C# version of revised code.

```
    public Point3D CalculateCentroid(List<Point3D> verticies)
    {
        var s = new Vector3D();
        var areaTotal = 0.0;

        var p1 = verticies[0];
        var p2 = verticies[1];

        for (var i = 2; i < verticies.Count; i++)
        {
            var p3 = verticies[i];
            var edge1 = p3 - p1;
            var edge2 = p3 - p2;

            var crossProduct = Vector3D.CrossProduct(edge1, edge2);
            var area = crossProduct.Length/2;

            s.X += area * (p1.X + p2.X + p3.X)/3;
            s.Y += area * (p1.Y + p2.Y + p3.Y)/3;
            s.Z += area * (p1.Z + p2.Z + p3.Z)/3;

            areaTotal += area;
            p2 = p3;
        }

        var point = new Point3D
        {
            X = s.X/areaTotal,
            Y = s.Y/areaTotal,
            Z = s.Z/areaTotal
        };


        return point;
    }
```